# how to delete table records based on conditions in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have small doubt in SQL server .

I have 3 databases and each database has some tables:

`database1` has tables `test`, `test1`, `test2`.

`database2` has tables `sa`, `sa1`.

`database3` has some tables like `emp`, `dept`, `loc`.

Based on these databases, I want truncate table data based on conditions:

1. Current day is `Thursday` and time is `6:40PM` then truncate `database1` related tables data
2. Current day is `Friday` and time is `12:00AM` then truncate `database2`  related tables data.
3. Current day is `Saturday` and time is `3:20AM` then truncate `database3` related tables data.

I tried like:

```
select  
   case when datename(dw,getdate())='Thrusday' and   RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar,getdate() ,100), 6) AS [Time]='6:40PM'
   then 
       truncate table database1.dbo.test
end
```

But, it's not giving the correct result.

Please tell me how to achieve this task in SQL server.

Comment: I would love to answer your question. But I don't want to decode it first

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to create several SQL Agent jobs to achieve your goal.
For example, create job that starts every Thursday at 6:40 PM. In a job you can add SQL step, which truncate\delete appropriate data.

If your server is Express edition and Agent is not installed, you have to use standard Window's scheduler to execute process which connects to database and executes appropriate statements.